# Condition on matrix to give a cylinder

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus

The question is to put a condition on the 2x2 matrix $H$

which is in the form

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
z & w\\
-\bar{w} & \bar{z}\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

where z and w are complex numbers.

such that with that condition you get a cylinder (ie $S^1$ x [a,b])

The answer is supposed to be

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
e^{i\theta} & c\\
-c & e^{-i\theta}\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Where $c \in R$

And I have no clue why,

Comment: "get" a cylinder how? By considering $\{(z,w)\in\Bbb C^2\}$ satisfying the conditions?

Comment: I asked the prof later, the question was what can we do to this matrix so that it would reduce to the mathematical form of a cylinder.